# Usage of set -e in Bash

Tags: bash

In this script

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
exec svlogd ./main
```

Do you know what set -e does? I searched man and Google without luck

Comment: `man bash | less -p '-e'`: fifth match...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to improve your google-fu.

`help set`:

> ```
> -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
> ```

Comment: I should improve my help-fu